# Open file in R which related corresponding to system date

Tags: r, csv, datetime

I would like to use R to verify system date first prior to go to my default work directory to open today and the day before data file.

The reason is my data file been labelled as 20151101_xxx.csv which is yyyymmdd_xxx.csv. Is it possible R can perform this action?

Comment: Yes. Hint: Look at `Sys.Date()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I try to use below comment: t1 <- as.character(Sys.Date()-1)
t <-as.character(Sys.Date()) but not sure how to remove the "-". Reason change it to character is due to going to replace this into next comment

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Is `paste0(format(Sys.Date()-1,"%Y%m%d"),"_xxx.csv")` what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list.files` to do that as follows:

```
days <- gsub("-", "", Sys.Date() - 0:1)
list.files(path = "YOUR PATH", pattern = paste0(days, "_", collapse = "|"))
```

Which gives you all files starting with `yyyymmdd_`.

To only get files in the format `yyyymmdd_xxx.csv` do the following:

```
list.files(path = "YOUR PATH", pattern = paste0(days, "_xxx.csv", collapse = "|"))
```

This should give you all files containing `yyyymmdd_xxx.csv`.

Comment: A tip: you can use `Sys.Date()` in combination with format: `format(Sys.Date(), format="%Y%m%d")`

Comment: Thanks. unfortunately i have multiple file 20151101_xxx.csv, 20151101_yyy.csv, 20151031_xxx.csv, 20151031_yyy, etc. However, I just would like to open file 20151101_xxx.csv and 20151031_xxx.csv.

Comment: i get what i want but edit the below comment: days <- gsub("-", "", Sys.Date() - 0:1)
list.files(path = "YOUR PATH", pattern = paste0(days, "_xxx", collapse = "|")). thanks a lot